# Can't get my update functions to work with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm developing a SPA webapplication and I'm running into a problem. I have a input field that accepts text like so:

```html
<input type="text" 
       data-bind="typeahead: containers(), 
                  updater: containerupdatefunction, 
                  attr: { placeholder: 'ABCD-123456-7' }, 
                  event: { change: checkContainerNumber }, 
                  value: containerNumber, 
                  style: { backgroundColor: containerNumberCorrect() ? 'rgba(0,255,0,0.4)' : 'rgba(255,0,0,0.4)' } " 
       required />
```

Everything is loaded correctly. Here is what I want but can't get to work:

When I click the input field and enter a character I get a list with autocomplete words that works fine, *However*, when I click one of them the `update` functions both are triggered. If `containerupdatefunction` is triggered before `checkContainerNumber` then my value is loaded correctly but this only happens 1 out of 10 times.

I need those 2 update functions because this input field also allows the user to input a new number. But this needs to be checked first to.

Any idea how I can solve this? Something with ValueUpdate (already tried but okay)?

If the function that is housed in the event: `change{checkContainerNumber }` is triggered before the `updater:` then the value I get is the value of a couple of characters I entered. So not the autocomplete when I selected one of those.

Could someone please help, if there is something missing or you need more information please tell me.

Remember the updater function is only triggered when you click a value of the autocomplete list.

Here is the knockout-bootstrap binding:
// Bind twitter typeahead

```
ko.bindingHandlers.typeahead = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var $element = $(element);
        var allBindings = allBindingsAccessor();
        var typeaheadArr = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());

        $element.attr("autocomplete", "off")
                .typeahead({
                    'source': typeaheadArr,
                    'minLength': allBindings.minLength,
                    'items': allBindings.items,
                    'updater': allBindings.updater
                });
    }
};
```

Here is my modelview:

```
this.checkContainerNumber = function(item, element) {
            var t =  $(element.target).val();
        };

        this.containerupdatefunction = function(item, element) {
            var t = item;
            containerNumber(item);
            return item;
        };




        /*
        this.checkContainerNumber = function (item, element) {
            if (!updaterTriggered()) {
                if (containerNumber().length == 13) {
                    checkContainerNumberFunction(containerNumber());
                    updaterTriggered(true);
                } else {
                    containerNumberCorrect(false);
                }
            }
            return;
        };

        function checkContainerNumberFunction(containerNumberToCheck) {
            try {
                if (mapContainers[containerNumberToCheck].ContainerNumber() != undefined) {
                    container(mapContainers[containerNumberToCheck]);
                    return;
                }
            } catch(err) {

            }

            if (containerNumberToCheck.trim().length == 13 && containerNumberToCheck != undefined) {
                $.get(
                    "http://localhost:60312/api/baseapi/checkContainerDigit?digit=" + containerNumberToCheck,
                    function (data) {
                        if (data == true) {
                            containerNumberCorrect(true);
                        } else {
                            containerNumberCorrect(false);
                        }
                        updaterTriggered(false);
                    }
                );
            } else {
                containerNumberCorrect(false);
                updaterTriggered(false);
            }
        };

        this.updateViewAfterContainerSelection = function (item) {
            if (!updaterTriggered()) {
                updaterTriggered(true);
                containerNumber(item);
                checkContainerNumberFunction(containerNumber());
            }
            return item;
        };
        */
```

This is what I tried so far!

Comment: There is a lot of code missing from this question (like the `typeahead` binding), which makes it hard to answer. It would help a lot of you could reproduce the problem in a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: I have updated my question with your requested information